# How to use HttpPost to get the second response

Tags: android, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm use the HttpPost to obtain the web search result in thread.
The main questions is the response from the first httppost request is need to wait web deal with.
and I don't know how to do next step to get completely response result.

Please give me some hints or thoughts. Thanks in advance.

[issue response pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mXbYNgLTud9UnZz0QeNyIqJPMNIrpDKO),
[correct response pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rM2SZRGiqRUNr0TbxrrXJuIIswJxa8NI)

Below are my source code.

```
    try {
            String _url = "https://www.airfrance.com.tw/cgi-bin/AF/TW/zh/local/process/standardbooking/DisplayFlightPageAction.do";

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                String sessionID = response.getFirstHeader("Set-Cookie").getValue();
                cookiestore = httpclient.getCookieStore();
            }                
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // POST
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(_url);

            client.setCookieStore(cookiestore);
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("typeTrip", "2"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("departure", "TPE"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("departure", "CDG"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("departureType", "AIRP"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("departureType", "AIRP"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrival", "CDG"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrival", "TPE"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrivalType", "AIRP"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("arrivalType", "AIRP"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dayDate", "28"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dayDate", "10"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yearMonthDate", "201906"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yearMonthDate", "201907"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nbPassenger", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("paxTypoList", "ADT"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("selectCabin", "on"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("plusOptions", ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nbAdults", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nbChildren", "0"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nbEnfants", "0"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nbBebes", "0"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cabin", "Y"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subCabin", "MCHER"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("haul", "LH"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("familyTrip", "NON"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("calendarSearch", "1"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("flyingBlueMember", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("partnerRequest", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("corporateMode", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("isUM", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("optionalUM", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mandatoryUM", "true"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("standardMandatory", "true"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subscriberHOPContext", "false"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hopCardOption", "NO_ANSWER"));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hopCardType", ""));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("notFromFlight", "true"));


            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            post.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(post);

            int code = responsePOST.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Log.e(mTAG, "web code = " + code);
            if (responsePOST.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                HttpEntity resEntityPOST = responsePOST.getEntity();
                POSTresult = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityPOST);

            }
            mOTAFileThread = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Are you going to chain the requests?
Do you need your first response to start the second response?

Comment: @MichaelLam, In fact, I don't know how to chain the first and second request in one request.
I tried use one thread to get first response then use second thread to set second request, but fail, still not to obtain the correct response.

Comment: Please check out my answer and see if it gives you some hints in doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your custom `ResponseHandler` into `execute` method so that you can chain your second request inside it.

```
    // Create a custom response handler
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

        @Override
        public String handleResponse(
                final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                // The response of first request is available here
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
            } else {
                throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
            }
        }

    };
    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(responseBody);
```

Reference:

[Official Example of ResponseHandler](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientWithResponseHandler.java)

[Doc of Execute function](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html)

Apart from that, `okhttp / Retrofit` are much popular and powerful `HttpClient` in terms of android development. Please feel free to check it out.

[OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

[Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)